# Modeling with Constant and Continuous Variables

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to model/predict how much knee bend (angle created between your thigh and lower leg) impacts how fast you run, while including your height, weight and 500 meter time. I've just created some sample data, a 6'0" male that weighs 180, and has a 49.5 second 500 meter time. I've also just created some random numbers, labeled 'data', to act as my knee bend angle.

```
data <- data.frame(height = rep(72, 1000), 
                   weight = rep(180, 1000), 
                   data = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 50), 
                   lap = rep(49.5, 1000))
head(data)
```

My question is, how do I relate the variables that are constant (height, weight, 500 meter time) to a continuously changing variable(s) (knee bend - angle)?

The data here is not really important, I'm just confused on comparing the two types of variables.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so just to clarify: For every observation (person), you have its recorded weight, height, 500 meter lap time, **and knee bend**? In that case, just include them as predictors, e.g. `time ~ weight + height + knee_bend` (ignoring interactions for the moment).

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific. Assume the whole data set is information on one person, a 6'0" male that weighs 180, and has a 49.5 second 500 meter time. Each observation is the same person, just with a changing knee bend as he runs. That's why the weight, height and time aren't changing. So essentially, I'm trying to compare one observation (height, weight and time) to hundreds of observations of a changing variable. Thanks for your response!

Comment: I'm confused. You can't estimate the effects of `weight` and `height` on `time` if you have only one single observation. Provided I understood you correctly you have multiple `time` measurements for different `knee bends` of the same person. In that case you could regress `time` on `knee bend` within a standard (generalised) linear model `time ~ knee bend`. If you had multiple persons, for each of which you had `knee bend`/`time` data, then this could be described within a hierarchical/nested effect model.

Comment: I'm trying to model the "perfect" knee bend. Assume I sampled 1000 people, got their height, weight, and 500 meter time. I then sample their knee bend continuously as they run. Then you walk in, I want to be able to tell you what your knee bend "should" be based on your dimensions. Again, I really appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Comment: No problem @Ben. The more I (think I) understand your problem, the more I’m leaning towards a hierarchical model as the way forward. This is what I would do: Assume the `knee_bend` measurements to be drawn from a normal distribution `knee_bend[i] ~ N(mu_knee_bend[i], sigma_knee_bend[i])`, where the indices `[i]` denote individual persons. We can then model `time = beta_0 + beta_1 * height + beta_2 * weight + beta_3 * mu_knee_bend + (interaction terms) + epsilon` within a simple linear model with `epsilon ~ N(0,1)`. [...]

Comment: [...] Such a hierarchical (nested effect) model would be easy to set up in e.g. `rstan`/Stan, and you could include some sensible priors on the model parameters `beta_i`, as well as `mu_knee_bend` and `sigma_knee_bend`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help!